# Bootstrap sass, qual a melhor maneira de uso para evitar redundância de atributos

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, sass

Estou utilizando a versão sass do boostrap, e gostaria de saber qual a prática recomendada.

Eu tenho os `assets` originais do bootstrap e tenho os meus `assets` pessoais que creio eu sobrescrevem os do boostrap, assim eu não mexo nos originais do boostrap.

Minha dúvida é: vale a pena mexer nos arquivos originais do bootstrap ou eu utilizando da maneira como estou, o próprio compilador verifica se já existe a declaração e sobrescreve deixando apenas uma referência no css gerado?

Comment: Seria por exemplo, você importar todo o style do bootstrap mas usar o seu próprio css para dar estilo aos botões?

Comment: Isso, só que ao invés de importar o css do BS eu uso a versão `sass`

Comment: Mas você já está pegando a versão 4? Ou ainda na 3? Só fiquei confuso com a parte que diz que está usando o sass, que só possui na versão 4.

Comment: Já existe o BS em sass na versão 3 a muito tempo http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Comment: humm.. Bom saber. Vou ver se consigo analisar bem para elaborar uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de questão, a meu ver, depende de muitos fatores no seu projeto. Mas, assim como você, também tive essa dúvida quando comecei a mexer com css no bootstrap. Tudo é muito mais fácil, mas ao mesmo tempo, tudo é tão fechado, pois os estilos são fixos e sempre que precisamos mudar algo, temos que reescrever aquele css.

#### O que eu analisei:

- Necessidade/Praticidade de utilizar o código Bootstrap vs meu código;
- Desempenho do site;
- Organização do projeto;
- Benefícios em usar o Bootstrap;

De fato o bootstrap é uma excelente ferramenta, mas por exemplo, vamos analisar os 'botões' do bootstrap.

Você precisa realmente de todo o `css` referente a eles? O css puro de botões do bootstrap tem mais de 500 linhas de códigos. E se você precisar alterar algo ali no meio, é fácil/viável? Não vai interferir em outro tipo de botão (flat, ghost, gradiente)? E se você escrever um código para sobrescrever esse botão, será que ele vai funcionar? Ou vai precisar de um `!important` bagunçando ainda mais a hierarquia?

Ou então uma questão ainda mais simples a se analisar, quão difícil seria para criar meu próprio estilo de botão?

Eu, por exemplo, tenho um sass chamado `_buttons` nele eu criei meu próprio 'framework' de botões. Possuo

- 3 estilos: flat, outline e underline.
- 4 tamanhos: botões de tabelas, pequenos, médios e grandes;
- 5 cores: info, default, success, warning e danger;

Isso tudo com um total de +- 100 linhas, incluindo estados alternativos de `:hover` e `:active`. Nesse estilo eu consigo mesclar e criar os mais diversos botões, tamanhos e cores.

Neste caso, não foi necessário, muito menos vantajoso, ter toda a estrutura de botões que o bootstrap fornece. Não iria ser útil, nem de fácil manutenção, fora as diversas linhas de códigos que economizei e o tamanho do arquivo: 160kb do bootstrap todo `vs` 4kb do meu button.scss (ou 60kb do projeto todo - incluindo muito mais css);

---

Mas, na área de grid, por exemplo, o bootstrap tem um css excelente! Nesse caso, também criei um arquivo sass chamado _grid, onde literalmente copiei todo o grid do bootstrap e fiz algumas pequenas alterações, como mudar o nome das classes para ficar com a 'cara' do meu projeto, mas a funcionalidade em si é toda do bootstrap.

---

Ou seja, mesclei o que havia de melhor no bootstrap (pelo menos para aquela necessidade, para aquele projeto) com o que seria mais prático para mim.

Manter os dois arquivos vai exigir muita atenção na organização do projeto, criação de classes, para não criar classes com o mesmo nome, fora o tamanho dos arquivos, pois você vai ter 2 arquivos potencialmente grandes de css para muitas vezes sobrescrever quase que no total a função de um ou de outro. Fora que, muitas vezes nem é usado todo o css do bootstrap, como o css de affix, helpers, breadcrumbs, etc..

Recomendo que você faça uma ordem de necessidade:
- Resete de css;
- Estilos comuns (grid, alertas, notificações, etc..);
- Estilos modulares (botões, formulários, pagination, etc..);

E faça uma mescla do que você pode criar e do que é mais vantajoso usar pronto.

Lógico, tudo depende do projeto também. Muitas vezes não temos prazo, muito menos orçamento para isso. Mas espero poder te dar um norte melhor.